# Magento2 change Luma header template

Tags: magento2.2, luma-theme

We want to edit the Magento2 Luma header template, this so we can change the sort inside

```
<div class="header content">
```

We want to place the block search before the minicart for example and place the logo block inside a new `<div>`

Where can we find the right template files for this?

So to change this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create default.xml under ***app/design/frontend/PackageName/themeName/Magento_Theme/layout*** directory

```
  <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart"/>
         <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
             <container name="custom-block-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom.block.container" >
            </container>
         </referenceContainer>
         <move element="logo" destination="custom-block-container" after="-"/>
```

Let me know if works.
It is working into Luma theme my side.

Comment: Only the first line of your answer is required isn't it?

Comment: In default luma theme,  top search is displaying after minicart .
Requirement is "We want to place the block search before the minicart for example"

Comment: That's what this line does - `<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart"/>`. The other lines create a new container, move the logo and add a class which doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: so, what is your solution?:)

Comment: You have the solution already, `<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart"/>` on it's own should do the job as that moves the search to be before the minicart.